# R vector programming: How to aggregate data efficient

Tags: r, vectorization, aggregation

I have data like this:

```
 | ID | Value | Condition
 | ---|-------| ---------
 | 01 | NA    | Start_1
 | NA | 1     | NA
 | NA | 1     | NA
 | 04 | NA    | Start_2
 | 14 | 4     | NA
 | 15 | 4     | NA
 | 16 | NA    | End_2
 | 17 | NA    | Start_3
 | NA | 4     | NA
 | 27 | NA    | End_3
 | 28 | 5     | NA
 | 29 | NA    | End_1
```

I want to aggregate the values between `Start` and its related `End`.

More precisely, it should be the sum of the values from a start, `Start_x`, until its related `End_x`. If there is a further start `Start_y` before the end `End_x`, then the values from `Start_y` until `End_y` (or until a further `Start_z`) are related to `Start_y`. Also, the related IDs should be listed.

So the solution should be something like this:

```
Start_1: Sum of Values: 7; IDs: 01,NA,28,29  
Start_2: Sum of Values: 8; IDs: 04,14,15,16
Start_3: Sum of Values: 4; IDs: 17,NA,27
```

In non-vector based programming languages I would define a looping function such as:

```
**for** all rows:
   **if** there is a start do ...
   **if** there is a end do ...
   **if** there is a NA do ...
```

But that is not an efficient solution for R since it works with vectorization. Do you have any tips for solving that more efficient?

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the data

Comment: The data is 2862679 observations of 48 variables. So I can't show you the whole data here.

Comment: You don't need to show the whole dataset.  Just 10 rows or so i.e `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata, 10)))`

Comment: I apprehend, this would not be helpful. Here is the first line of the output of dput(droplevels(head(yourdata, 5))): structure(list(NewProcess = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), NewThreadId = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), NewThreadStack = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), ReadyThreadStack = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_,